# Get the Selected row of Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview.I placed checkbox on each row.By selecting the checkbox and clicking on delete button i should get all the selected row of that gridview in the codebehind.Please do help me...

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="#DEBA84" 
        BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
        CellSpacing="2" style="margin-left: 58px; margin-top: 13px" >
          <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
          <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                  </EditItemTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" Text="Button"  runat="server" 
        onclick="Delete_Click" />
```

codebehind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string valueForDB = DatabaseList.SelectedValue;
        Data obj = new Data();
        if (valueForDB == "virtualworkplace")
        {
            obj.getDocforVirtualwrkspace(valueForDB);
            GridView1.DataSource = obj.getDocforVirtualwrkspace(valueForDB);
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
What to write here???
 protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 private void DeleteRows()
 {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView1.Rows)
        {
            HtmlInputCheckBox chk = (HtmlInputCheckBox) row.Cells[0].FindControl("selectedrowchk");
            if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
            {
                string id = gridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); // get the record's ID of this row
                deleteRecord(id);
            }
        }

        //RefreshGrid();
    }
```

This code is assuming you set the DataKeyNames property of the GridView to store the primary key of each record. It is also assuming you are putting the checkbox in the first column

Comment: how to set  DataKeyNames in GridView ?

Comment: how do you store the record ID in the gridview? It could be in hidden field as well. `<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="PrimaryKeyID" .... >` where PrimaryKey should be replaced with UserID, ProductID, etc

Answer (score 2):

to set datakeys use the datakeynames property from the gridview

```
 <asp:GridView AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" 
        PageSize="10" DataKeyNames="MembershipNo"  
        ID="grdvw_showdetails" runat="server" CellPadding="4"
```