# pass multiple parameters to java script function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i want to pass multiple parameters to a java script function through code behind
like this only i want to pass 
`<script type="text/javascript"> function addmultiple(param1 ){}</script>`

for ex: 1,john,39,200,'insert';2,peter,30,300,'insert'(these fields should pass in the above parameter).

in code behind i am binding all data's through a grid view. and i want to pass the value's to java script function by separation of semi colon. after that next row should be bind. 
i am doing these all in asp.net

advance thanks

Comment: can you post what you've tried?

Comment: not sure what ur asking but you can pass as many parameters u want to js function, just add a comma after each parameter

Comment: @ brwwzer, i can pass multiple parameter by separation of comma.on doubt for me, that for eg: m1,mensred,1,1200,1,0,0;m1,mensred,1,1200,1,0,0;m1,mensred,1,1200,1,0,0;m1,mensred,1,1200,1,0,0;m1,mensred,1,1200,1,0,0; like this i am having 15 values , how can can i pass this 15 values to a single parameter

Comment: @VinothK: Those 15 values mean something right. Then create an object and pass the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function addmultiple(param1)
{
    alert(param1);
}
</script>
```

**To call function**

```
<script>
function insertData()
{
    //create an two dimensional array to store data
    var arr1= [[1,'john',39,200,'insert'],[2,'peter',30,300,'insert']];

    //addmultiple(1,'john',39,200,'insert'); //for single row

    //loop here for passing multiple rows
    for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
    {
    var row='';
        for(var j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            row = row + ',' + arr1[i][j];
        }
        addmultiple(row);
    }
}
</script>
```

**html code**

```
<input type="button" value="b1" onclick="insertData();">
```

Comment: its working correctly , one doubt there is multiple rows in grid view , how to separate every row ..

Comment: @VinothK i think you must ask a seperate question for this

Comment: @VinothK which grid you are using for displaying records?

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>

Comment: @VinothK please check the following links, they might help to solve your issue, [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775253/get-the-selected-row-of-gridview) ,  [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It should just be:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function addmultiple(param1, param2, param3)</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var param1='1,'+'name1,'+'30,'+'300,'+'insert,';
  var param1='2,'+'name2,'+'40,'+'400,'+'insert,';
  addMultiple(param1,param2);



  function addMultiple(param1,param2){
   //your code
  }
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you constraint is you need to pass only one parameter, You can might as well create an object and add the params as the properties to that object and pass the object alone.